# Add a line at the top of a page without affecting the other pages

Tags: fancyhdr

I would like to add a line at the top of a page of my thesis but without affecting the other pages . In fact it is the page of citation and it looks weird, so I would like to add this line

P.s only line without writing any thing. I have tired:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

but unfortunately it affects all the pages.

Thank you

Comment: You can also use tikzpagenodes with (current page header area).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\thispagestyle` to affect only one page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,RE,LE,LO,CO,CE]{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE,RE,LO,CO,CE]{}


    \renewcommand\headrule{%
            \hrule width \hsize%
    }%

    \renewcommand\footrule{}%

}

\begin{document}

    \thispagestyle{mystyle}

    \lipsum[1]

    \newpage

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Which gives you [image]

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx Please next time illustrate what you need with a picture and don't forget to vote up and accept the answer that solves your problem.